# When do I use setState in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

As newbie in flutter it's very confusing for me when use `setState` in `Flutter` application. In below code boolean `searching` and var `resBody` used inside `setState`. My question is why only `searching` and `resBody` inside setState? Why not others variable?

```
var resBody;
bool searching =  false,api_no_limit = false;
String user = null;

Future _getUser(String text) async{
setState(() {
  searching = true;
});
user = text;
_textController.clear();
String url = "https://api.github.com/users/"+text;
  var res = await http
      .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": 
           "application/json"});
  setState(() {
    resBody = json.decode(res.body);
  });
}
```

Comment: It depends on where inside or outside a widget the code is. From your question this can't be derived.

Comment: any good source to learn about this topic?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html, https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/. I'm sure there are several tutorials and YouTube videos, but I have no links at hand. I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI a good introduction.

Comment: In simple words, when you change the value of variable. It's the most basic.

Comment: but user variable is not inside setState but it still working inside app. Then how it's working in StatefulWidget? @goops17

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html
According to this, you don't need variable to be inside setState to change the value

Comment: that means searching and resBody both variable are okey without setState?

Comment: Can we user this setState method in utils class in constructor?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html):

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

So if the state of the widget changes **you have** to call `setState` to trigger a rebuild of the view and see immediatly the changes implied by the new state.

Anyhow the below snippets are equivalent.

first case (directly form `flutter create <myproject>`):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {

    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }
```

second case:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    _counter++;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

What I don't know is the reason why and if the first case is the conventional way to use `setState`, I would say because of readability of code.

Comment: The thing is, a lot of people are asking the very same question, _why_ the first approach is the convention. The doc says _"Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might be associated with the change."_ But what if my change is a large HD image which I read from a base64 string? What am I putting inside the `setState()`, if the reading and converting of the image is done before that?

Answer (score 22):

When you change the state of a stateful widget, use `setState()` to cause a rebuild of the widget and it's descendants.
You don't need to call `setState()` in the constructor or `initState()` of the widget, because `build()` will be run afterwards anyway.

Also don't call `setState()` in synchronous code inside `build()`. You shouldn't need to cause a rerun of `build()` from within `build()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure his question is about "Why don't we compute everything in the setState callback?"

Comment: @RémiRousselet that's absolutely right...do you know the answer and can put it in comment?

Answer (score 13):

If you look at the implementation of `setState`:

```dart
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    assert(fn != null);
    assert(...);
    final dynamic result = fn() as dynamic;
    assert(...);
    _element.markNeedsBuild();
  }
```

you see that the only things it does are: asserting a few things to help you debug incorrect usage of it, executing the callback, and marking the element so it gets rebuild.

So, technically, it doesn't matter if you change some variables inside the setState callback or outside of it, as long as `setState` is called.

However, for readability there is a big difference. Rebuilding widgets has impact on the performance of the app, so you want to do so as little as possible. Making all, and only those, changes to variables that require the widget to rebuild inside the `setState` callback makes it clear to people (including your future self) exactly why a rebuild is needed.

Answer (score 6):

When you need to change the value any widget shows on the screen. For example, in the app there was a task. After completion of which points should be added to the "wallet". But the problem is that we need to refresh the app to see points on the "wallet". To solve this we use Setstate() on Button Onpressed()

For example:

```
RaisedButton(
 
 onpressed(){
    
   setstate(){
      
     points+10;

   }
 }

)
```

Every time the button is pressed it will refresh the widget with the new value returned by the "wallet" variable without the need to restart the entire App.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to update a widget tree (generally with some new data), you call `setState`. It can only be used in `State` class. Here's the simple implementation:

```dart
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  int _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() => _count++),
          child: Text('Count = $_count'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setState()` is only being used with statefulWidget insides flutter. `setState()` tell the flutter to rebuild the page when something defined inside the `setState()` changes.

NOT: `setState()` is a callback function.

```
Text(questions[questionIndex])
```

Here I want to change the Text according to the given questions array, and on every button click, I want to increase the index by 1.

```
void answerQuesion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }
```

So, I have to put this index increment inside the `setState()`, so that flutter will rebuild the page after every change of questionIndex.