# Flutter - SetState method parameter usage

Tags: flutter

I have just started trying Flutter today. I am following the official tutorial: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive (this question involves Step #3)

I understand the idea of Stateful Widgets and the need for setState(), but I dont understand the point of its parameter (function). Why should we pass a function to it? Couldnt setState be parameterless and we then would simply put the state changing code (that we would put on that parameter function) right before calling setState?

So basically my question is: what is the difference between

A)  setState(() { myCounter++; });

and

B) myCounter++; setState( () {} );

?

Obs: on the tutorial I linked above if I do it either way the result is (or seems to be) the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283077/when-use-setstate-in-flutter/)?.

Comment: For future reference, after a month of learning Flutter I still dont really know the answer, it seems you can do either way, the only difference is that on approach A setState has some checks and will not execute the code inside it if the checks fail (invalid state, etc), while the B approach doesnt have those checks. Also, not a duplicate as suggested, and the single answer below also doesnt apply to the question (Im aware that I shouldnt lock the main thread with heavy computations, the question was not about that).

Answer (score 0):

The callback function is there to ensure that the changes you made to the models are synchronous and you should only set the things that you UI needs. 
This will ensure that the changes are set before the framework refresh the UI because you can't do async work on the callback and the result can be predictable.

If you have to do heavy computations you should do it before call setState.

In your example, it is the same because is just a simple variable increment, but in practice, if you have heavy operations or async operations and want running those. inside the callback can have a performance impact if allowed.

Check the oficinal documentation for more examples:  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: The doc says _"Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might be associated with the change."_ But what if my change is a large HD image which I read from a base64 string? What am I putting inside the `setState()`, if the reading and converting of the image is done before that?

Comment: You should create a async method, inside that do a await BigCompurationFunction() and then call setState. You can use setState in an async function. What you can not is pass an async fucntion to setState.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same doubt, I checked the code of `setState` and still could not find any special usage for method parameter. So I think the design of `setState` method parameter is not reasonable, let `setState` be a no parameter function is better for understanding:

```
myCounter++; 
setState();
```