# How change state in flutter?

Tags: flutter, checkbox, dart

I'm trying to make a checkbox with images. But i don't know how make the stateChange, i have declared a variable named `selected`. In the `GestureDetector` i change the value of `selected`, if the value of `selected` is the same of the `index` i put the border. But the border of the checkbox doesn't change:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../../models/champion.dart';

class FormularioTransferencia extends StatefulWidget {
  final Champion champion;
  String selected = '1';

  FormularioTransferencia({Key key, @required this.champion})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return FormularioTransferenciaState();
  }
}

class FormularioTransferenciaState extends State<FormularioTransferencia> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.champion.feName),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchPost(widget.champion.feName),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final champion = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
              return _championDetail(champion);
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  fetchPost(championName) async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://cms.paladins.com/wp-json/wp/v2/champions?slug=' +
            championName.replaceAll(' ', '-').toLowerCase() +
            '&lang_id=1');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      return response.body;
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }


  Widget _championDetail(champion) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _avatarPage(champion),
          _titlePage(champion),
          _titleTopic('talents', 30.0),
          _legendaries(champion),
          _titleTopic('abilites', 45.0),
          _abilites(champion),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _abilites(champion) {

    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                widget.selected = '1';
                debugPrint(widget.selected);
              },
              child: _abilityIcon(champion, '1'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                widget.selected = '2';
                debugPrint(widget.selected);
              },
              child: _abilityIcon(champion, '2'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                widget.selected = '3';
                debugPrint(widget.selected);
              },
              child: _abilityIcon(champion, '3'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                widget.selected = '4';
                debugPrint(widget.selected);
              },
              child: _abilityIcon(champion, '4'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                widget.selected = '5';
                debugPrint(widget.selected);
              },
              child: _abilityIcon(champion, '5'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _abilityIcon(champion, index) {
    var colorBorder =
    index == widget.selected ? const Color(0x547a8c00) : const Color(0x00000000);

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(width: 10.0, color: colorBorder),
          left: BorderSide(width: 10.0, color: colorBorder),
          right: BorderSide(width: 10.0, color: colorBorder),
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 10.0, color: colorBorder),
        ),
      ),
      child: Image.network(
          champion[0]['api_information']['Ability_' + index]['URL']),
    );
  }

  Widget _titleTopic(title, size) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Text(title.toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: size)),
    );
  }

  Widget _legendaries(champion) {
    final cards = [];
    for (var card in champion[0]['cards']) {
      if (card['rarity'] == 'Legendary') {
        cards.add(card);
      }
    }
    return SizedBox(
        height: 550.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
            primary: false,
            itemCount: cards.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 0, bottom: 16),
                child: _legendaryCard(cards[index]),
              );
            }));
  }

  Widget _legendaryCard(card) {
    String card_name =
        'https://web2.hirez.com/paladins/champion-legendaries-badge/' +
            card['card_name_english'].toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '-') +
            '.png';

    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 4, // 20%
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Image.network(card_name, scale: 1),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 6, // 20%
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 10.0, right: 20.0, top: 0, bottom: 16),
                    child: Text(card['card_name_english'].toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Text(
                        card['card_description']
                            .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\[.*?\] '), ''),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _avatarPage(champion) {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Image.network('https://web2.hirez.com/paladins/champion-headers/' +
          champion[0]['slug'] +
          '.png'),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 20.0,
        left: 20.0,
        child: _chooseIcon(champion),
      )
    ]);
  }

  Widget _chooseIcon(champion) {
    String role = champion[0]['api_information']['Roles'].toLowerCase();
    if (role.contains('front')) {
      return Image.asset('assets/images/front.png', width: 70, height: 70);
    } else if (role.contains('flanker')) {
      return Image.asset('assets/images/flank.png', width: 70, height: 70);
    } else if (role.contains('damage')) {
      return Image.asset('assets/images/damage.png', width: 70, height: 70);
    } else if (role.contains('support')) {
      return Image.asset('assets/images/support.png', width: 70, height: 70);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Widget _titlePage(champion) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Text(
              champion[0]['api_information']['Name_English'].toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 45,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white)),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(champion[0]['api_information']['Title'].toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: HexColor(champion[0]['frontend_info']['color_picker']),
              )),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(
              champion[0]['frontend_info']['role']
                  .replaceAll('Paladins', '')
                  .toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: HexColor('#547a8c'),
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are the `_championDetail()`, `abilities()` and `_abilityIcon()` methods declared inside the `FormularioTransferenciaState` class or outside? Because you may need to use different state management techniques in each case.

Comment: They are outside, but i remake the class and put them inside.

Comment: If they're inside the class you can simply use the `setState()` method to rebuild the UI whenever you update a value. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283077/when-use-setstate-in-flutter) out