# Flutter platform error when querying for data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

[image: firebase database]

Can I know how can I resolve this issue?

Flutter - PlatformException : error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1, null

The following is my code to query the name of my user.

```
class Auth {
  FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
  FirebaseAuth auth;
  final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;

  String name = '';
  String uid = "";

  void getCurrentUser () async {
    mCurrentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    uid = mCurrentUser.uid;
    print(uid);

  }



  void getName1() async {
    if(uid != null){
      DocumentSnapshot document = await Firestore.instance.collection('User').document(uid).get();
      name =  document.data['Name'];
    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that that the uid is not null when you call the getName1() function. Also please provide a log for the error. Its the only way to get to the depth of the problem

Comment: yea i printed uid out and it is not null. Can I ask how can I use the setState() function ?

Comment: setState basically rebuilds the screen whenever it is called and checks if there are some changes in the state of the associated widget and rebuilds it.
For more information: You can checkout this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283077/when-use-setstate-in-flutter

Comment: Also, please provide the log of the error while asking question, that's the only way we can find where is the thing going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  void getName1() async {
     FirebaseUser mCurrentUser = await auth.currentUser();
     DocumentSnapshot document = await Firestore.instance.collection('User').document(mCurrentUser.uid).get();
      name =  document.data['Name'];
  }
```

Create a local variable, and retrieve the current useruid inside the method `getName1()`

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't work. What do u mean by this "Create a local variable, and retrieve the current useruid inside the method getName1()"?

Comment: Just copy the answer, first you have uid equal to empty string so it will never be null, then you assigned the uid to it but you need to call setstate

Comment: hi, can you illustrate what u meant by setState? Sorry, I am quite new to flutter. Thank you

Comment: did the above code that I gave you work? What do you get from it?

Comment: hi, it doesnt query the name successfully. It prints out an empty string instead. Thanks

Comment: If you try to manually read one specific document that you know it exists for sure does it work ? For example in the code above try replacing .document(mCurrentUser.uid) with .document('[DOCUMENT_ID]')  and in document_id just copy paste on document ID from the list you show in the question. If this works then the issue is within the generated uid or the code that creates those docs in the first place. @user13739409

Comment: thanks for the help! When i query for it when I input the uid manually, it works. I think the issue lies in the code that creates the document.