# I need to press the button 2 times in order to function (flutter)

Tags: flutter

I have a problem implementing a login button, when I press it, it will not function at first, but when I press it again (same value fields) it works.

here's my code
Button:

```
 Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
                              setState(()  {
                                onPressedLogin(userName.text,password.text);
                              });
                            }
```

The OnPressedLogin():

```
void onPressedLogin(String userName,String password) async{
bool isValid = false;
var value = await dataBaseHelper.getUserList();
for(User userOB in value){
  //print(userOB.password+" "+password),
  if(userName == userOB.username && password == userOB.password) {
    isValid = true;
    this.password.clear();
    this.userName.clear();
    inputTextColor = Colors.grey[850];
    invalidCredentials = "";
    print("YES");
    //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    break;
  }
}
if(!isValid){
  inputTextColor = Colors.red[800];
  invalidCredentials = "Invalid Credentials";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a Future but in `setState()` you are not waiting for it so that's way it work in the second press (the value take time to change).

To make it work with single press you have to a wait the Future to complete before rebuilding, here how:

First change the return type of the function

```
Future<void> onPressedLogin(String userName,String password)
```

Then in the `RaisedButton`

```
onPressed: () async {
  await onPressedLogin(userName.text,password.text);
  setState(() {});
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The moment you setState(), the UI will refresh!
Probably that's the issue, let me explain:

What you should do is to call your function before setState(), so that the screen is refreshed with the new info.

```
Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
                             onPressedLogin(userName.text,password.text);
                          setState(()  {
                            //Variables that change for the refresh.
                   
                          });
                        }
```

In your specific case, I don't see the need for SetState() as you are only printing values in log, not changing the UI.

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: I am changing the UI on the OnPressedLogin()

Comment: Then, I do it this way:

Imagine you had at the start of your code

String logged = "False"; 

Your onPressedLogin should/could return a new value for counter

logged = onPressed....

And then, refresh UI

setState(){
}

Check out this link: I think you do not fully understand SetState

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283077/when-do-i-use-setstate-in-flutter

Good Luck

Comment: yeah it is my first time on flutter(1 1/2 week) BTW I did figure it out thanks to the answer above, my function is a future so yeah, putting async on the onPressed: () async do the job