# How is the class variable being updated without calling setstate?

Tags: flutter

How am I able to get the updated value of the `TextFormField` without using `setState((){})`?

On `TextFormField` 's `onChanged` method, I am setting the class variable to the value, but normally we would need `setState((){})` for the value to be updated. I am just wondering how is this working?

```
class ResetPasswordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResetPasswordPage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ResetPasswordPageState createState() => _ResetPasswordPageState();
}

class _ResetPasswordPageState extends State<ResetPasswordPage> {

String _currentPassword = '';

  void onChanged(){
    print('current Password is: ');
    print(_currentPassword); ----------->this is printing the updated value, without setstate?

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       TextFormField(
         onChanged: (val) => {
           _currentPassword = val,
           onChanged()
         },
      ),
    )
 }



}
```

Comment: You're already doing ``_currentPassword = val`` while the ``setState({})`` is used to rebuild widgets !! More @ https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I use setState in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283077/when-do-i-use-setstate-in-flutter)

Comment: @OMiShah thanks for the links! sorry I was in a confusion that to even update the class variable you will need to use `setState((){})`, it's all clear now! I will have to use setState only when I want to rebuild the widget (more of visual than actual value)
For example, If I am displaying the text typed by the user in a Text() widget, then I should use setstate so the Text() widget will immediately gets rebuilt to show the updated text

Comment: yeah...you got it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable value does change without the need to use setState, setState is only needed to tell Flutter that the UI has to change to reflect changes in your data.

***From [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html):***

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Notifier -> listener, then set the listener to listen for the Notifier,so any update on the Notifier(controller)it will notify the listener(TextFormField) to update itself.

Like this:

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();

child: TextFormField(
    controller: _controller,
    decoration: //decoration,
),
```

when you call this **_controller.text** it will notify all the listeners of this TextEditingController that needs update, then you get the same result setState((){}) will give you.