# setState deosn't show changes correctly on UI

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I click **Run Query** button I get the expected result in the terminal but I have to click it once again to be able to display the result in the UI!

I guess there is something wrong in `setState` usage. May you please help me to find out what's wrong?

PS. I tried to use both suggested cases of `setState` mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51299522/2015609) but I always get the same result.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MySQL Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'MySQL Test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? _barcode;
  late bool visible;

  @override
  var Connection;
  String? res;

  void initsql() async {
    try {
      var settings = ConnectionSettings(
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: 3306,
          user: 'root',
          db: 'testo',
          password: '1234',
          timeout: Duration(minutes: 2));
      Connection = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
      print("Connected");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void getResult() async {
    var results = await Connection.query('SELECT id, Name FROM testo.mytable');
    for (var row in results) {
      res = 'ID: ${row[0]}, Name: ${row[1]}'; //---> Needs Double click!
      print('ID: ${row[0]}, Name: ${row[1]}');
    }
  }

  void initState() {
    initsql();
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              res == null ? 'Disconnected!' : '$res',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                            //---> Needs Double click!!
                            getResult();
                          }),
                      child: Center(child: Text('Run Query'))),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `getResult` method is asynchronous, so the return type is not `void` but `Future<void>`.

```
  Future<void> getResult() async {
    var results = await Connection.query('SELECT id, Name FROM testo.mytable');
    for (var row in results) {
      res = 'ID: ${row[0]}, Name: ${row[1]}'; //---> Needs Double click!
      print('ID: ${row[0]}, Name: ${row[1]}');
    }
  }
```

The reason why you UI doesn't update the widget on your first tap is, that your  `getResult` is asynchronous. In your button you call `setState`, which triggers a rebuild of your widget, but since the method is asynchronous, it cannot provide a result immediately when it is started. This means you call `setState`, it updates your UI, then your method retrieves the new value of `getResult`, but the UI got updated before that. To fix this you have to wait for your method until it has finished and then call `setState` to update your UI.

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        await getResult();
        setState((){});
      } ,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Run Query'),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the good explanation

Answer (score 1):

[image]

@qouci explained well instead converting you fuction future.you can also use like this .add setstate after asyn query execution.

**Widget**

```
           ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => getResult(),
                child: Center(child: Text('Run Query')))
```

**QueryExecution**

```
 void getResult() async {
    var results = await Connection.query('SELECT * FROM test.sys_config;');
    for (var row in results) {
      res = 'ID: ${row[0]}, Name: ${row[1]}'; //---> Needs Double click!
      print('ID: ${row[0]}, Name: ${row[1]}');
    }
    // ------------------------------------here
    setState(() {
      res;
      //---> Needs Double click!!
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @lava your approach is much better.