# Why doesn't the widget rebuild with the setState function?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, angular-dart

I would like to rebuild the widget, when the value of the variable 'player' changes. The variable 'player' is a global variable.
The class spielerAnzeige is a stateful widget and i also called setState but nothing happens.

```
class spielerAnzeige extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<spielerAnzeige> createState() => _spielerAnzeigeState();
}

class _spielerAnzeigeState extends State<spielerAnzeige> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {});
    return Text("Spieler $player ist an der Reihe!",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40));
  }
}
```

Comment: This website is English only. Please edit your question to English

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51283077/11382012 see this thread for more information on proper usage of setState(() {});

Comment: Calling the setState during the build is an error. Check out InheritedWidget, or Provider package, or bloc package, basically you need better state management than just setState().